# Create Android tree-uri from directory tree-uri and filename

Tags: android

Given a tree-uri obtained from the `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` intent and which references a directory, and given the display name string (e.g. `myfile.jpg`) of a file that exists within that directory, how do I build a tree-uri that refers to that file?

Conceptually, what I'd like to do is "append" the filename to the directory tree-uri to obtain a valid file tree-uri. Is there a way to do this - preferably efficiently?